# Trying to populate a ng-select component and @ngrx/store from the store but giving undefined the response

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

This is the outputs and the code is in this link
[github snippet](https://github.com/jmanuelc87/mapas-dinamicos/commit/85d2cf5727a9ad91f0fa67a4879c27ab20c61584?diff=unified)

[image: Stacktrace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
import { createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
```

to get an slice from the app state and another function to get an slice to the property you need.